# How to add 'C linker flags while building electron app

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder, node-gyp

I am developing an electron app on which i need to set a c compiler header to allow prelogin interactions

Ref: [How to simulate keyboard and mouse events using CGEventPost in login window mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429524/how-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-events-using-cgeventpost-in-login-window-mac)

I am not sure how to add these headers in Nodejs based Electron project. Can someone help on this.